# IMFSourceReader giving error 0x80070491 for some resolutions

Tags: frameworks, media, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to catpure video from a 5MP UVC camera using an IMFSourceReader from Microsoft Media Foundation (on Windows 7 x64).  Everything works just like the documentation with no errors on any API calls until the first callback into OnReadSample() which has "0x80070491 There was no match for the specified key in the index" as it's hrStatus parameter.

When I set the resolution down to 1080p it works fine even though 5MP is the camera's native resolution and 5MP (2592x1944) enumerates as an available format.

I can't find anything in the the Microsoft documentation to say that this behaviour is by design but it seems consistent so far. Has anyone else got IMFSourceReader to work at more that 1080p?

I see the same effects on the Microsoft MFCaptureToFile example when it's forced to select the native resolution:

```cpp
HRESULT nativeTypeErrorCode = S_OK;
DWORD count = 0;
UINT32 streamIndex = 0;
UINT32 requiredWidth = 2592;
UINT32 requiredheight = 1944;
while ( nativeTypeErrorCode == S_OK )
{
    IMFMediaType * nativeType = NULL;
    nativeTypeErrorCode = m_pReader->GetNativeMediaType( streamIndex, count, &nativeType );
    if ( nativeTypeErrorCode != S_OK ) continue;

// get the media type 
    GUID nativeGuid = { 0 };
    hr = nativeType->GetGUID( MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &nativeGuid );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;

    UINT32 width, height;
    hr = ::MFGetAttributeSize( nativeType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &width, &height );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;

    if ( nativeGuid == MFVideoFormat_YUY2 && width == requiredWidth && height == requiredheight )
    {
        // found native config, set it
        hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType( streamIndex, NULL, nativeType );
        if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;          
        break;
    }

    SafeRelease( &nativeType );
    count++;
}
```

Is there some undocumented maximum resolution with Media Framework?

Comment: Quick update on this, the IMFSourceReader callback fails on any resolution OTHER that 1080p.  640x480 and 720p both fail with the same error as 2592x1944.

Comment: Confirmed on Lenovo ThinkPad Integrated Camera. 352x288 doesn't work in Media Foundation but works in DirectShow. Seems Mf is still non-compatible with most cameras.

It reports it's supported but in reality async reader just doesn't work and sync reader returns this error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with the camera I was using, NOT the media streaming framework or UVC cameras generally.

I have switched back to using DirectShow sample grabbing which seems to work ok so far.

Comment: I'm running into this exact same problem - specifically with one camera. Do you know what it was about the camera that caused this? I'm trying to avoid re-writing my application for DShow.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was using Media Foundation under Win7? Got the exact same problem right now...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem on windows 7 with a usb camera module I got from Amazon.com (ELP-USBFHD01M-L21).  The default resolution of 1920x1080x30fps (MJPEG) works fine, but when I try to select 1280x720x60fps (also MJPEG, NOT h.264) I get the 0x80070491 error in the ReadSample callback.  Various other resolutions work OK, such as 640x480x120fps. 1280x720x9fps (YUY2) also works.

The camera works fine at 1280x720x60fps in Direct Show.

Unfortunately, 1280x720x60fps is the resolution I want to use to do some fairly low latency augmented reality stuff with the Oculus Rift.

Interestingly, 1280x720x60fps works fine with the MFCaptureD3D sample in Windows 10 technical preview.  I tried copying the ksthunk.sys and usbvideo.sys drivers from my windows 10 installation to my windows 7 machine, but they failed to load even when I booted in "Disable Driver Signing" mode.

After looking around on the web, it seems like various people with various webcams have run into this problem.  I'm going to have to use DirectShow to do my video capture, which is annoying since it is a very old API which can't be used with app store applications.

I know this is a fairly obscure problem, but since Microsoft seems to have fixed it in Windows 10 it would be great if they backported the fix it to Windows 7.  As it is, I can't use their recommended media foundation API because it won't work on most of the machines I have to run it on.

In any case, if you are having this problem, and Windows 10 is an option, try that as a fix.

Max Behensky